# Running an operation on each 2 consecutive variables in Python?

Tags: python

I have a Python list like:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

And I want to run an operation on each two consecutive variables. For example I want to sum each two consecutive variables in the list and put them into another list:

```
newlist = [1+2, 3+4, 5+6, 7+8]
```

But how can I do that in Python? I didn't know where to start. Should I use two nested for loops, or enumerate, or zip function? I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite way to do this is with an explicit `list_iterator`.

```
itr = iter(mylist)
newlist = [x + y for x, y in zip(itr, itr)]
```

`zip` advances the iterator by two elements each time it yields a pair. The benefit of using an iterator over slicing is that it doesn't require you to make two half-copies of the list before zipping.

---

If you don't like two lines, Python 3.8 can fold the assignment into an expression:

```
from operator import add

newlist = list(map(add, (i:=iter(mylist)), i))
```

(For some reason, you can't use an assignment expression in a list comprehension.

```
[x + y for x, y in zip((i:=iter(mylist)), i)]
```

is a syntax error, but

```
t = zip((i:=iter(mylist)), i)
[x + y for x, y in t]
```

is fine. I suspect it has something to do with scoping, but I don't know the technical details.)

Comment: it's beautiful *tear*

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `zip()`:

```
out = [a+b for a, b in zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2])]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 7, 11, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `range()` function defaults to increment the sequence by 1, but one can increment the value by adding a third parameter - `range(start, stop, step_size)`.
You can try this:-

```
res = [mylist[i]+mylist[i+1] for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1, 2)]
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
[3, 7, 11, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
mylist =[n+mylist[i-1] for i,n in enumerate(mylist) if i%2]
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 11, 15]
```